# Prove a specific property for tetrahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have the following question.

If the heights from vertices $A$ and $D$ in tetrahedron $ABCD$ intersect then $AD$ and $BC$ are perpendicular.

I draw a sketch of the tetrahedron but I don't have any idea how to show that.
All I know is that I must show that $AD \cdot CD =0$

Answer (score 2):

Take a plane $\pi$ through $B$ and $C$: for any point $P$, let $P'$ be the projection of $P$ on $\pi$.
Assume that $E$ is the projection of $A$ on the $BCD$-plane and $F$ is the projection of $D$ on the $ABC$-plane. We have $A'E'\perp BC$ and $D'F'\perp BC$, hence if $AE$ and $DF$ meet at some point, 
$$ A'D'\perp BC $$
holds and your claim follows.

To draw this has been a nightmare, but I hope the following picture helps:

[image]